# What http referer should I set on the browser key of Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've got browser key for using Google Javascript API on my Android app.
Google API will be called on html file, which is set on webview.
So I'd like to us by specifying

```
file:///" domain, in Webview.loadUrl()
```

, and so I think HTTP referer should be `file:///*`.
But when I set it Google API doesn't work and return IOException.

When I set nothing it works well without any errors.
But this condition is not recommended for the security reasons.
Does anyone know what I should set as HTTP referer?

Comment: Javascript API? Or Android API?

Comment: I'll use Javascript API.

Answer (score -1):

According to the HTTP referrer placeholder in the console, the *.example.com/* should indeed work.
In practice, though, this indeed doesn't seem to be the case.
It was able to solve the issue by simply setting the referrer to: example.com
There is no single pattern that matches both cases, you can use 2 referers:
*.example.com/* example.com/*
For more information, have a look at [Registering authorized URLs](According to the HTTP referrer placeholder in the console, the *.example.com/* should indeed work.

In practice, though, this indeed doesn't seem to be the case.

It was able to solve the issue by simply setting the referrer to: example.com

There is no single pattern that matches both cases, you can use 2 referers:
*.example.com/* example.com/*
For more information, have a look at Registering authorized URLs).